# Javascript 'this' keyword in String.prototype.replace function

Tags: javascript, string, replace, this, slice

Why I can't do something like this:

```
string.replace(this.slice(0,1), '');
```

The error log:

```
TypeError: this.slice is not a function
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: Because `this` refers to it's parent context (The function it's executing inside).

Comment: @LucasCosta I want to delete the first character

Comment: `var str = 'test'; str.replace(str.slice(0,1), '');`

Comment: @kg2152 This code will delete all copies of the first character. So `abracadabra` will become `brcdbr`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

To delete the first character of a string, do:

```
string = string.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For delete the first character try this

```
string.replace(/^./, '');
```

or

```
string.slice(1)
```

Examples:

```
var st = "hello";

var a = st.replace(/^./, ''); // "ello"
var b = st.slice(1); // "ello"
```

Comment: Your regexp code will only delete the first character if it's a letter, number, or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Or, the way you are doing..

```js
var str = "HOME";
console.log(str.replace(str.slice(0,1), ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the issue while maintaining your original code, you can use the following code:

```js
let string = "string";
let newString = string.replace(string.slice(0,1), '');
console.log(newString);
```

But this is kind of a roundabout way to only delete the first character, and it will also replace any other occurrences of the first character in the string.

You can just use the slice method to return a string with the first character removed from the original string:

```js
let string = "string";
let newString = string.slice(1);
console.log(newString)
```

Unless it is your intention to have a space occupying the first letter.

Remember: this refers to the execution context of the function being called. Assuming you are calling string.replace(this.slice(0,1), '');
in the global context without strict mode enabled, this would refer to the global object. If you had strict mode enabled, then this would refer to undefined. Either way, it is not referring to the string you are calling replace on.